# col-sm-2 me ocupa toda la fila con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

tengo este codigo con bootstrap, en la que el div que contiene la imagen (zapatos.jpg) deberia en pantallas pequeñas ocupar un largo de 2, y en grandes un largo de 1. Pero me aparece como veis en la foto esta: https://postimg.cc/Q99tz33r , que es en una pantalla pequeña, y aparece como si ocupara toda la fila osea 12. Como se ve en la foto, aparece la imagen y coloreado en color secondary toda la columna que ocupa toda la fila.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="jsBootstrap/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsBootstrap/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class='row align-items-center'>
            <div class='col-sm-2 col-lg-1 bg-secondary' >  
                <img class='d-block' src='zapatos.jpg' style='width:75px;height:93.75px;'>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-10 col-lg-11'>
                <div class='container'>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-8 bg-danger'>
                            <div>Nombre</div>              
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4 d-sm-block d-lg-flex flex-lg-row-reverse'>
                            <div class='d-lg-inline-flex d-sm-flex'>precio</div>
                            <div class='d-lg-inline-flex d-sm-flex'>unidades</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qué versión de Bootstrap estás usando? Las versiones 3 y 4 utilizan ancho completo (12 col) para resoluciones menores a las que se indican, en este caso, usaría 2 columnas a partir del breakpoint correspondiente a sm, y 12 columnas para resoluciones menores a ese breakpoint

Comment: la version de bootstrap es la v4.4.1, pero he actualizado a la 5 y sigue igual

Comment: en vez de utilizar el break point `sm` utiliza `xs` ó en todo caso evita los break points y solo pon: `col-2` y `col-10`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

parece ser que bootstrap 4 en adelante no cuenta con tamaño xs. En mi codigo no uso xs sino que uso sm, pero deberia usar xs para pantallas pequeñas. En bootstrap 4 en adelante en vez de col-xs-2 se utiliza col-2. Entonces lo he resuelto y queda asi:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="jsBootstrap/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsBootstrap/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class='row align-items-center'>
            <div class='col-2 col-lg-1 bg-secondary' >  
                <img class='d-block' src='zapatos.jpg' style='width:75px;height:93.75px;'>
            </div>
            <div class='col-10 col-lg-11'>
                <div class='container'>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-8 bg-danger'>
                            <div>Nombre</div>              
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4 d-sm-block d-lg-flex flex-lg-row-reverse'>
                            <div class='d-lg-inline-flex d-sm-flex'>precio</div>
                            <div class='d-lg-inline-flex d-sm-flex'>unidades</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```